# automatically Application close when in apps dialog open in cocos2d android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, cocos2d-android

i am trying implement in apps purchase in cocos2d game. i use extend CCLayer scene() in cocos2d. when i click on button of in-apps purchase than payment dialog is open but my application is close in back-end. i don't know how this happen.

Comment: i also have this type of problem so need to solve it.

Comment: Hi, in which way you have solved this issue as i am also facing and searching for solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think its due to - **`finish()`**. May be you have called the finish() in your **`onPause()`**. In my case i mistakenly wrote it in onPause for that reason when i clicked the buy button of **IAP**, always dialogue appeared but game window closed automatically.

```
@Override public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        CCDirector.sharedDirector().pause();
        //finish();
    }
```

After commenting out the **`finish()`** method my problem solved. :)